# JEE6 - CDI - DI at execution time

Tags: java, java-ee-6, cdi

I would like to know if Jee6 support dependency injection at execution time ...

I'm probably involving multiple concepts, so i try to describe the architecture i would like to have

1. A jar which contains an Interface

> public interface Hello  {
>        public String say(); }

a war referencing the interface (so the interface Hello jar is packed in WEB-INF/lib)

```
@WebServlet("/HelloServlet")
public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Inject @Any 
    Instance<Hello> hello;
    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public HelloServlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
          PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            out.println(hello.iterator().next().say());
    }
```

Ok , so i can achieve that with any issue

Basically i want to have multiple producer for that interface

```
@Named
public class HelloImpl implements Hello {

    @Override
    public String say() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return "TEST";
    }

}
```

So easy right, but now i don't know to make this modulable (can add or remove implementation during runtime) :

1. If i put the implementation in a war file, its run on another context right ?
2. If i put it in jar file i need to put in in the first war WEB-INF to use it right ?
   and can i add or remove jar dynamically during execution, i guess no ... or yes itm not very familiar with class loader and unloading jar files

Best Question, if all of that can be done, if there any way to r**aise event on jar is add**ed to web-inf/lib and / or removed ?

Lets say i'm not ready to go to OSGI but my problem may be cover by some functionnaly of that technology, i just want to stay in jee6 if i can ..

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could look at @Specializes or @Alternative or simply using different qualifiers with your producers and classes. You'd then need to choose which one you want to use by iterating through them with Instance.

Comment: thanks for that, my question is just more about managing dependancy dynamically, without restarting the server for loading and unloading . like an osgi bundle

Comment: CDI purposefully is managed at deployment time. If you're within a server you're really limited to what's going on with their integration. If you're in an SE situation then you can control this better.

EDIT: Of course if you want to dig into the impl being used you may be able to do what you want but it won't be portable.

Answer (score 0):

Look into producers with `InjectionPoint`, such as `@Produces Hello obtainHelloImpl(InjectionPoint ip)`.

This article will likely be of great help http://java.dzone.com/articles/cdi-di-p2.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Glassfish as Application Container you should have a look at this https://blogs.oracle.com/arungupta/entry/totd_154_dynamic_osgi_services

I used it a few years ago, but I'm no longer 100% sure if this worked also with

```
    @Inject
    @Any
    Instance<MyService> myServiceInstances;
```

or if I had to do a little bit more OSGI magic